# Disabling only left swipe on UITableViewCell.

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

My main view controller includes a table view and also a separate view on the right that folds in when the user pans left.

I have setup a **PanGestureRecogniser** on this controller so that the user can use it to switch between the two views. It works fine except for one issue.

When there are only one or two cells, the user needs to pan using the empty area at the bottom not covered by cells. When there are cells that cover the entire view, or when the user pans left, the cell's swipe to delete function gets activated, since a pan gesture always fires a swipe gesture.

I want to keep the swipe-to-delete feature, but **ONLY** when a user swipes right on a cell.

Any left swipes/pans should always unfold the second view on the right. I'm using a custom UITableViewCell subclass. Is there any way to disable **ONLY** the left swipe to enter the delete mode?

Comment: Have you tried creating a UISwipeGesture *swipe = [[UISwipeGesture alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doFoldOutAction)]; [swipe setDirection:UISwipeRightDirection]; and adding it to your UITableView ?

Comment: Wouldnt that override the swipe-to-delete for the cells? I need to keep that function, but override only the left swipe. I am assuming you meant to write `UISwipeLeftDirection` so that the left swipe triggers the foldout? I will try that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible.

Here's the code. Add the same to your `- (void) viewDidLoad` method:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * newSwipeGR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:nil];
newSwipeGR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
newSwipeGR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.myTableView addGestureRecognizer:newSwipeGR];
```

Still enable the deletion mode as normal, but you're now find that the delete swipe only works in one direction.